# Unterschied zwischen "Anklage" und "Beschwerde"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I am trying to grasp the difference between these two words. Here are the Duden entries for ["Anklage"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anklage) and ["Beschwerde"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beschwerde). Both words mean something like "a complaint" but the examples do not help to understand the difference. [First link in google](http://www.juraforum.de/forum/t/unterschied-zw-klage-und-beschwerde.69172/) appears to be a legal forum, I cannot understand the discussion there either.

Could you please provide examlpes that help understand the difference between these words?

Comment: there are other usages but most of the time "jemanden anklagen" means "to sue somebody" (i.e. Anklage is a legal term)

Answer (score 4):

"Anklage" is a legal term, and could probably be translated to "accusation". It is almost exclusively used for legal issues, f.e. if someone is accused of a crime, he's being "angeklagt".

"Beschwerde" is used very similair to the english word "complaint". If a customer isn't satisfied with a service, he can make a complaint, "eine Beschwerde".

Answer (score 4):

*Anklage* is primarily a complaint *officially lodged against you by a state prosecutor with a court of law, which might result in a fine or jail term*. That is quite a bit more serious than simply any old complaint!